# Call the constructor in the implementation of virtual pure function throws "allocating an object of abstract class type" error

Tags: c++

Hi I have this interface:

```cpp
template <typename S> class SourceStream {
public:
  using source_item_t = S;
  using source_pos_t = std::tuple<size_t, size_t>; // this can be overrided.

  virtual ~SourceStream(){};
  virtual auto eat(size_t) const -> SourceStream<S> = 0;
  virtual size_t getLine() const = 0;
  virtual size_t getColumn() const = 0;
  virtual source_item_t getStream() const = 0;
  virtual bool isEnd() const = 0;
};
```

and this implementation

```cpp
// the basic stream source stream implementation.
class BasicStringStream : public interface::SourceStream<std::string_view> {

private:
  source_pos_t position; // use the default
  source_item_t stream;

  // private constructor used to update the position.
  BasicStringStream(const std::string_view &s, const source_pos_t pos){};

public:
  BasicStringStream(source_item_t s)
      : stream(s), position(std::make_tuple(0, 0)){};

  source_item_t getStream() { return stream; };
  size_t getLine() { return std::get<0>(position); }
  size_t getColumn() { return std::get<1>(position); }
  bool isEnd() { return stream.empty(); }

  auto eat(size_t n) -> interface::SourceStream<source_item_t> {
    // call the constructor here
    return BasicStringStream(stream.substr(n), [=]() {  
      assert(stream.size() >= n);
      auto new_position{position};
      for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        auto ch = stream[i];
        if (ch == '\n') {
          std::get<0>(position)++;
          std::get<1>(position) = 1;
        }
        std::get<1>(position)++;
      }
      return new_position;
    }());
  }
}; // namespace cppparsec
```

The funcion `eat` tries to construct a new BasicStringStream, but it's a virtual pure function, and it's not implemented yet in the function definition. The compiler throws "allocating an object of abstract class type ..." error.

I know I can reconstruct the code, but I want to know is there any way to get around of this?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that you are returning *by value*, so you’re slicing your subclass.

Comment: `eat` returns an `interface::SourceStream<source_item_t>`. It's impossible to have an `interface::SourceStream<source_item_t>` because it's an abstract class.

Comment: ok I get it now, it's becuause in c++ you can't return a abstract class direclty. thank you!